# Big Fiware Deployments in IoT

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Can someone please post a link to examples of bigger Fiware deployments in IoT domain?

Is Santander the biggest deployment of this kind, as it has 12k sensors - which is big, but not impressive - impressive would be 12M as then you would need clustered broker to accept all these connections. I guess 12k connections can be handled with a single PC machine (no need for clustering).

I am interested in benchmarks (latency and throughput) and stability of Orion and other Fiware components, and want to know if some bigger commercial system is deployed on Fiware, or is it just in experimental phase and not suitable for professional deployments yet.
BR,

Drasko

Comment: Stockoverflow is not a good place for opinion based discussions, like if one technolgy is "suitable for professional deployments"

Comment: I think that http://ask.fiware.org would be a better place.

Answer (score 2):

In the FIWARE LAB Global instance of Orion we are currently processing about 160,000 instances at present.

FIWARE components are also part of private companies commercial portfolios, not only public instances for testing like the FIWARE Lab mentioned above. For instance, Orion CB and the IoT Agents are used by Telefonica Smartcity commercial product at present.

If you are interested in the components performance/scalability more than a existing deployments (that depends more on the current customers of the companies rather than the technology limits) you may check the performance tests that will be published during this year.

Cheers,